# Testing AJAX create action using Test::Unit (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My `tasks` CRUD methods are all done at the moment via ajax and I'd like to test that functionality using Test::Unit.  Is that possible?

I'm following along in the Agile Web Development with Rails book, and there is a reference to a test that tests similar functionality (but with Prototype).

```
test "should create line_item" do 
  assert_difference('LineItem.count') do
    post :create, :product_id => products(:ruby).id
  end

  assert_redirected_to store_path
end
```

I've modified it as follows:

```
test "should add task via ajax" do
  assert_difference "Task.count" do
    xhr :post, :create, :task => tasks(:one)
  end
end
```

There error I keep receiving is:

`ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method '<=' for nil:NilClass`

So my first attempt is to look where that is being caught.  It's in my create.js.erb file, where I have some logic where I figure out where the new task belongs in the sectioned list of all tasks.

```
<% if @task.due_date <= Date.today %>
  var id = "#tasks_today";
  var desc = null;
<% end %>
...if statements continue...
```

So I'm assuming that @task isn't being passed to create.js.erb when the test is working itself out, but when I manually test things work perfectly.  Here's my controller:

```
respond_to :js

def create
  @task = current_user.tasks.new(params[:task])

  if @task.save
    respond_with(@task)
  end
end
```

Is Test::Unit not built to test with Jquery?  Would this only work with Prototype?  Am I doing it completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the due_date for your @task instance is nil and that case is not handled.  Try changing the code to

```
<% if @task.due_date.present? && @task.due_date <= Date.today %>
```

Comment: Hrm.  I'll give that a shot.  Shouldn't the due_date be set when I pass in the fixture?  My fixture does contain a due_date for this particular task object (tasks(:one)).  I even have a before_create in my model that defaults the due_date to today if there isn't one. :(

Comment: No luck.  I'm beginning to think that Test::Unit doesn't interpret the ruby code correctly.  <= isn't a method; it's a comparison.  Isn't due_date the method?

Comment: @Steve also, there is a problem with the parameters you are passing to the xhr call.  You should pass a hash of values like you would get from submitting a form through a post request instead of a task instance.

`xhr :post, :create, :task => {:due_date => 3.days.from_now}`

Comment: @Steve <= is a method, and Ruby uses a bit of syntactic sugar so that you don't need a dot to call it. You can call operator methods using dots, however. This works `1.<=(2) # true` and is equivalent to `1 <= 2`.